# Fb.ui() share don't shown user custom message

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Custom text which user enter in popup:
http://monosnap.com/image/koz7B5cQgs2MyYH2Fr0ZDTwm6kPnux.png

Don't show on facebook:
http://monosnap.com/image/vs4rsYk5eCiknJllTSCESQibjh2biT.png
i mean "1111111"

even if i use before share:
FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});

still havent message

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: '856902511027949',
      status : true, 
      cookie : true, 
      xfbml  : true, 
      oauth  : true, 
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  });

  $(".init").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
      display: 'popup'
    }, function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });

  });
});
```

code: http://jsbin.com/cahoziteza/2/edit?html,output
example: http://jsbin.com/cahoziteza/2

**Update**
asked Facebook about this, they said it's a bug
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/797358463644104/

Answer (score 0):

You can´t add a message, at least not anymore. It would not be useful anyway, because it is not allowed to prefill the message according to the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> 2.3: Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Comment: But why if user doing share from mobile, his custom message appears on Facebook. And if fb took this opportunity, why did they leave the possibility to the user enter custom message?

Comment: share from mobile is not with the share dialog, it´s probably with publish_actions and /me/feed posting.

Answer (score 0):

hi you need ad this line, this lne add a note in your publication

FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
      display: 'popup'
      **quote:'mensagge'**
    }, function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });

});
});